# TexturePacker and Cocos2d iPhone - blurry sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I'm using TexturePacker to generate sprite sheets. I have images sized perfectly for retina iPhone, I'm using AutoSD feature in TexturePacker to pack them to sprite.png and sprite-hd.png. Both png files look sharp. When I test my game in retina emulator it looks crisp, everything's fine. However when I run 480x320 iPhone in emulator and my regular sprite.png loads - sprites look blurry.
When I manually resized all my individual sprite files and created a sprite sheet from them using TexturePacker it looked fine too.
I was hoping TexturePacker would save me some time doing things manually, and I can't understand why my sprites look blurry. Please help.

Comment: I've found you can't always rely on graphic appearance on the simulator.  Is the issue the same on device?  Would also be useful to see the parameters you are passing to texture packer for generating the atlases.  Perhaps there are some flags which are working against each other.

Comment: Just tested on iPhone - same thing, parameters are default, smooth scaling and everything else is ok. The resulting png looks very nice. I think positioning and sprite size can cause this blurriness and I'm experimenting with these. Running out of ideas though (